# Running the same test multiple times with different setups

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testunit, shoulda

Does anyone know of a nice dry way to run the same group of tests in different contexts.  Here is a ridiculous example of wanting to run the same tests with two different setups.  I don't want to have to repeat the same tests just so I can have different setups.

```
context 'cat' do
  setup do
    @object = cat
    ....
  end

  should 'walk' do
    assert @object.walk?
    ...
  end

  should 'run' do
    assert @object.run?
    ...
  end
end

context 'dog' do
  setup do
    @object = dog
    ....
  end

  should 'walk' do
    assert @object.walk?
    ...
  end

  should 'run' do
    assert @object.run?
    ...
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done it with `merge_block` before. Define a class method in your test that returns a `Proc` of your shoulds and then merge it in where appropriate.

```
def self.walk_and_run
  Proc.new do
    should 'walk' do
      assert @object.walk?
    end
    should 'run' do
      assert @object.run?
    end
  end
end

context 'cat' do
  setup do
    @object = cat
  end
  merge_block(&walk_and_run)
end

context 'dog' do
  setup do
    @object = dog
  end
  merge_block(&walk_and_run)
end
```

Comment: This works, but I'm having a hard time moving that proc into a context so my test doesnt get cluttered.  Once I move the proc into the context, I can't figure out how to reference it in the merge_block statement.  You know what I mean?

Comment: Yeah, I know what you mean. Because it needs to be a class method it has to live outside the context. You might be able to set a variable in the context to be the Proc and merge that in rather than defining it as a method that returns a Proc. It might still look a bit messy though.